# How can I specify animations-path for SWF animations?

Tags: xetex, mac, animations, media9

In graphics documents, one can use

```
\graphicspath{ {/Users/masi/Dropbox/Physiology/images/} }
```

for images.
It is not for animations like SWF media.
Now, I have to keep those animations in the main directory.

I want to specify path like this

```
\animationspath{ {/Users/masi/Dropbox/Physiology/animations/} }
```

**How can you specify animations-path for SWF animations?**

My try on AlexG answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\addmediapath{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Physiology/animations/}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=200pt,
  height=150pt
]{}{Heartaxis.swf}
\end{document}
```

but I get the error in the typesetting engine XeLaTeX

```
Undefined control sequence. (\addmediapath ...).
```

Comment: If `\addmediapath` is not defined, you are using an old version of `media9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acc. to the  `media9` documentation:

```
\addmediapath{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Physiology/}
```

Comment: I get "Undefined control sequence. (\addmediapath ...). Which packages are you using?

Comment: @Masi: `media9`, of course.

Comment: I added the code of my try to my question body. Are you using same minimal tex code?

Comment: @Masi: Yes, I did. You may need to update your TeX installation and the packages therein (MiKTeX-2.9 or TeX-Live 2013).

Comment: I have OSX and MacTeX-2013 so it should be TeX-Live 2013, but probably some bugs. Which typesetting engine are you using?

Comment: TL 2013 on Linux. `tlmgr update --all --self` should bring you to the state of the art ;)